# java.lang.unsatisfiedlinkerror: no vtk CommonJava in java.library.path

Tags: java, ubuntu, vtk

I'm fighting with this error:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no vtkCommonJava in java.library.path

I'm trying to use the vtk with Scala. I also tried a Maven-Project, which already worked on a collegues computer. On my notebook, I tried it with windows 7 and ubuntu linux 13.10.

I hope, someone could give me a hint, how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the jvm where the natives for the vtk library is located.

To do this, run the jvm with the argument -Djava.library.path="path/to/natives".

Comment: What are the native files exactly for vtk? I know only where the vtk.jar is placed. Before, I compiled vtk with cmake and wrapped vtk to Java.

Comment: I am not familiar with vtk, I would not know.